# mvc c# nonmapped property that retrieves total row count

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have 2 classes, with a one to many relationship

```
public class team
{
  public int ID {get;set;}

  **public int TotalPlayers{get{return registeredPlayers.Count();}}**

  //edit
  private ICollection<registeredplayers> registeredplayers;
  public ICollection<registeredplayers> registeredPlayers{
     get {return registeredplayers ?? (registeredplayers = new List<registeredplayers>());}
     set {registeredplayers = value;}
  }
}

public class registeredplayers
{
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public string name {get;set;}
   public int teamid {get;set;}
   public virtual team team {get;set;}
}
```

**so whenever i call the property would return 0**, even if there are multiple players registered.

```
TotalPlayers = entity.TotalPlayers.First(p => p.ID == 1);
int totalplayers = team.TotalPlayers
```

any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what is being asked for, but I don't see how the code provided would compile.

How you return the count depends on what implementation of an IEnumerable you would be using, the interface itself does not provide a prototype of a method that would do this. I tend to use generic lists so I would use:

```
public class team
{
  public int ID {get;set;}

  public int TotalPlayers{get{return registeredplayers.Count();}}

  public System.Collections.Generic.List<registeredplayers> registeredplayers{get;set;}
}
```

Also the line

```
TotalPlayers = entity.TotalPlayers.First(p => p.ID == 1);
```

Doesn't make much sense to me as this property only has a 'get' accessor and so you could not assign a value to it.

Hope this helps, if I've missed the point please post back with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: hi, sorry, i had to edit the code. i forgot to put in more details on the registeredplayers. and it was an icollection instead of an ienumerable. i did a get on that since the registeredplayers are being provided by a private property. oh yeah and the question was that the totalplayers is returning 0.